# How do you run `npm prepare` on local modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I'm trying to split off a portion of my code into it's own local module, but keeping it in the same path.  I followed https://medium.com/@arnaudrinquin/build-modular-application-with-npm-local-modules-dfc5ff047bcc including

```
"preinstall": "rm-local-modules",
```

Which works in `npm@5+`

However, his instructions do not specify how to trigger the `npm install` in the local module.  In the `package.json` of the local module I have

```
"prepare": "tsc"
```

Right now I execute it via script to generate the `dist` folder, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do that.  Ideally with a devDependency that does it.

```
"prepare": "rm -rf node_modules/@devhaus && cd local_packages/@devhaus/react-auth-provider && npm ci",
```

And this works with `npm install` and `npm ci`